# BAD ACCESS ZOMBIE EXCEPTION

Tags: ios, xcode, malloc, instruments, zombie-process

I have some troubles with a app, and I have no idea of where the source of problem.

I think that could be part of UINavigationBar, because throw error when i push back button from my view, but Instruments says that the error are in child view.

Can someone give me a hand with this?
[instruments log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQv7r.png)

This is the log of Instruments Zombie.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code provided, it is not possible to locate the error. But you could do the following:
1) Use ARC (automatic reference counting). With ARC, you should not have any overrelease of objects, as you obviously have. I strongly recommend to use ARC. It make life MUCH easier.
2) Enable exception breakpoints: In the navigator pane of Xcode, select the breakpoint tab, and click at the plus sign at left bottom. Select exception breakpoints and say done. Then the program will stop at the point where the overrelease is done. You could check then which object was released too early.

Comment: Thanks, with the exception I could see that the error was a delegate bad established